# Query <p> tags nested in <table> tag

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I search my MariaDB Database for

tags that are used in a  tag?

I tried

`WHERE content LIKE %<table>*<p>*</table>%`

and tons of other combinations BUT does not work.

Sample Code

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><p>Hello</p></td>
<td><p>Hello1</p></td>
<td><p>Hello2</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please help

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Is your HTML well formed (eg no missing end tags)?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have add on sample code in our questions pls check

Answer (score 1):

You may add more `%` and `LIKE` to query wildcards or use `.*` with `RLIKE`.

See example with working fiddle below:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    content text
);

insert into my_table(content)
values 
('This is <table><tr><td><p>Amazing </p></td></tr></table> content'),
('This is not <p>Amazing </p> content');
```

---

**Query #1**

```sql
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE 
        content RLIKE '.*<table>.*<p>.*</table>.*';
```

```
| id  | content                                                          |
| --- | ---------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 1   | This is <table><tr><td><p>Amazing </p></td></tr></table> content |
```

---

**Query #2**

```sql
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE 
        content LIKE '%<table>%<p>%</table>%';
```

```
| id  | content                                                          |
| --- | ---------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 1   | This is <table><tr><td><p>Amazing </p></td></tr></table> content |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xgtwRs7RDsCsmzWM19JgHd/1)

Let me know if this works for you.